# Regex Ignore Space

Tags: java, regex

With a lot of trying I have managed to create the following regex. I want to use this to prevent the spamming of IP's.

```
([0-9]{1,3}(\.+|\s+)){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

This will catch all the ips if written correctly

for example `8.8.8.8`

However it doesn't match `"8. 8. 8. 8"` or `"8 .8 .8 .8"`
`\s*`

But I don't seem to get it working, could anyone help me, and explain me where I need to place the `\s*` to ignore Spaces in between

Regards Jurre

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html Scroll down to "IP Adresses"

Comment: Looks a little loose to be validating ip's. Are the ip's in the middle of strings? Whitespace class includes CR, LF's as well.

Comment: Not validating IP's need them to block spam. I have these annying kids who keep spamming there Server Ip on my site, even though its not related to there game. Just cause it looks like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to allow white spaced anywhere in an IP address:

```
^\s*([0-9]{1,3}\s*\.\s*){3}[0-9]{1,3}\s*$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/zZ9kH6

Comment: Thanks! This sites works way better then the one I was using.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\s*(?:(?:[2](?:[5][0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\s*(?:\.\s*(?=[0-9])|(?![0-9]))){4}$
```

should do it.

To break this down,

1. `(?:[2](?:[5][0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` matches any non-negative decimal integer of at most three digits in the range [0,255].
2. `\s*` matches zero or more spaces.
3. `(?:\.\s*(?=[0-9])|(?![0-9]))` matches a dot and space when followed by more digits or the end of the digits
4. `{4}` requires four repetitions of this whole

To make it more readable, you can break it down:

```
String INT_IN_0_TO_255 = "(?:[2](?:[5][0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
String OPTIONAL_SPACE = "\\s*";
String DOT_BEFORE_MORE_NUMBERS = "(?:\.\s*(?=[0-9])|(?![0-9]))";
String NUMERIC_IP_ADDRESS =
   "^"
   + OPTIONAL_SPACE
   + "(?:"
   + INT_IN_0_TO_255
   + OPTIONAL_SPACE
   + DOT_BEFORE_MORE_NUMBERS
   + "){4}$";
```